# Why can I open my Spring application within Eclipse using Tomcat, but cannot access it when deployed directly in Tomcat?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, tomcat

I'm having a problem accessing my Spring Bott app in a Tomcat, as well as my React application.
Facts:
I have a SpringBoot application which is exported as a WAR file. I developed this with Eclipse. If I start Tomcat V.9 within Eclipse, I can reach my RestController. However, if I export the project and deploy it directly within Tomcat, I get a 404 error.
2: I have a REACT application, which I also stored within Tomcat. If I start Tomcat here via the startup.bat file, I can access my REACT application, but not my Spring Boot application. Conversely, when I start Tomcat in Eclipse as mentioned, I can access my Spring Boot application, but not my REACT application. What is wrong here ?

Code for Spring:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BuyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BuyApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(BuyApplication.class);
 }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.sessions</groupId>
<artifactId>Einkaufsliste</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Einkaufsliste</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<description>Einkauf App</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>13</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20201115</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
        <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>            
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

***EDIT***

[image]

Comment: Can you show the webapps folder in tomcat in both cases ?

Comment: @Shawrup I have made

Comment: Can you add a sample api calls you make to your spring boot app ?

Comment: @Shawrup const url = "http://localhost:8080/Einkaufsliste/Anmelden"

Comment: Did you change the port to 8085? default is 8080. Also you can rename your war to ROOT.war and try to access without EinkaufApp path. Also it might be helpfull if you can add the sc of the exception. I am guessing eclipse deploy your war as ROOT.war but you are deploying the with a different name.